# Chat app in Python; problem with sending and receiving usernames

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, networking, p2p

client.py asks users for entering a username and it shows in the terminal line. When the users send messages they see their usernames in terminal but as the usernames won't be sent to the server, server sees them as host and port so as the others. I want to send the usernames to the server and server will call them with their usernames. server.py is this:

```
    # server.py

import sys, socket, select

HOST = '' 
SOCKET_LIST = []
RECV_BUFFER = 2048 
PORT = 1969

def chat_server():

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
server_socket.listen(10)

# add server socket object to the list of readable connections
SOCKET_LIST.append(server_socket)

print "Chat server started on port " + str(PORT)

while 1:

    # get the list sockets which are ready to be read through select
    # 4th arg, time_out  = 0 : poll and never block
    ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(SOCKET_LIST,[],[],0)

    for sock in ready_to_read:
        # a new connection request recieved
        if sock == server_socket: 
            sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
            SOCKET_LIST.append(sockfd)
            print "Client (%s, %s) connected" % addr

            broadcast(server_socket, sockfd, "[%s:%s] entered the room\n" % addr)

        # a message from a client, not a new connection
        else:
            # process data recieved from client, 
            try:
                # receiving data from the socket.
                data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                if data:
                    # there is something in the socket
                    broadcast(server_socket, sock, "\r" + '[' + str(sock.getpeername()) + '] ' + data)  
                else:
                    # remove the socket that's broken    
                    if sock in SOCKET_LIST:
                        SOCKET_LIST.remove(sock)

                    # at this stage, no data means probably the connection has been broken
                    broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr) 

            # exception 
            except:
                broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr)
                continue

server_socket.close()

# broadcast chat messages to all connected clients
def broadcast (server_socket, sock, message):
for socket in SOCKET_LIST:
    # send the message only to peer
    if socket != server_socket and socket != sock :
        try :
            socket.send(message)
        except :
            # broken socket connection
            socket.close()
            # broken socket, remove it
            if socket in SOCKET_LIST:
                SOCKET_LIST.remove(socket)

if __name__ == "__main__":

sys.exit(chat_server())
```

and this is client.py:

```
# client.py

import sys, socket, select

username = raw_input("Enter a username: ")  # type: str

def chat_client():
if(len(sys.argv) < 3) :
    print 'Usage : python client.py hostname port'
    sys.exit()

host = sys.argv[1]
port = int(sys.argv[2])

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(2)

# connect to remote host
try :
    s.connect((host, port))
except :
    print 'Can not connect to server.'
    sys.exit()

print 'Connected to chat server. You can now send messages'
sys.stdout.write('[' + username + '] '); sys.stdout.flush()

while 1:
    socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]

    # Get the list sockets which are readable
    read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])

    for sock in read_sockets:            
        if sock == s:
            # incoming message from remote server, s
            data = sock.recv(4096)
            if not data :
                print '\nDisconnected from chat server'
                sys.exit()
            else :
                #print data
                sys.stdout.write(data)
                sys.stdout.write('[' + username + '] '); sys.stdout.flush()     

        else :
            # user entered a message
            msg = sys.stdin.readline()
            s.send(msg)
            sys.stdout.write('[' + username + '] '); sys.stdout.flush() 

if __name__ == "__main__":

sys.exit(chat_client())
```

Comment: It's not really clear what is the problem you're having. Please post the error you're getting and\or add details what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do some small changes to have it working:

### Server

Add a new data structure and expect to be receiving a username along with a new connection

```
HOST = '' 
SOCKET_LIST = []
USERNAMES = {}    #new data structure
RECV_BUFFER = 2048 
PORT = 1969

def chat_server():

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
server_socket.listen(10)

# add server socket object to the list of readable connections
SOCKET_LIST.append(server_socket)

print "Chat server started on port " + str(PORT)

while 1:

    # get the list sockets which are ready to be read through select
    # 4th arg, time_out  = 0 : poll and never block
    ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(SOCKET_LIST,[],[],0)

    for sock in ready_to_read:
        # a new connection request received
        if sock == server_socket: 
            sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
            SOCKET_LIST.append(sockfd)
            #wait to receive the username, you may want to set a timer and handle the case in which no username is sent for whichever reason
            username = sockfd.recv(1024)    
            print "Client (%s, %s) connected" % addr
            # add a key - value pair to be able to map a connection to a username
            USERNAMES[sockfd.getpeername()] = username   

            broadcast(server_socket, sockfd, "%s entered the room\n" % username) 

        # a message from a client, not a new connection
        else:
            # process data received from client, 
            try:
                # receiving data from the socket.
                data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                if data:
                    # there is something in the socket
                    broadcast(server_socket, sock, "\r" + '[' + str(USERNAMES[sock.getpeername()]) + '] ' + data)  #use the data structure previously defined to send the correct usernames
                else:
                    # remove the socket that's broken    
                    if sock in SOCKET_LIST:
                        SOCKET_LIST.remove(sock)

                    # at this stage, no data means probably the connection has been broken
                    broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr) 

            # exception 
            except:
                broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr)
                continue

server_socket.close()

[...]
```

### Client

Send the username as the connection gets established

```
username = raw_input("Enter a username: ")  # type: str

def chat_client():

[...]

# connect to remote host
try :
    s.connect((host, port))
except :
    print 'Can not connect to server.'
    sys.exit()

print 'Connected to chat server. You can now send messages'
sys.stdout.write('[' + username + '] '); sys.stdout.flush()

# immediately send the username
s.send(username);
while 1:
    [...]
```

Of course you may want to implement some security like setting a timeout on the server when receiving the username, but this should be working as you want